# SSRS - where ... is no more than 30 minutes longer than

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I want it to only display if i.ClosedDate is between 0 to 30 minutes more than e.eCreationTime

So if i.ClosedDate is 30+ minutes more than e.eCreationTime it won't show

**Sorry, I was struggling to explain.**

```
select e.eMapName
, e.eFolderName
, i.Status
, i.AssignedTo
, i.ClosedDate
, e.eCreationTime

From ework.eFolder e inner join ework.Incident_Management i
on e.eFolderID = i.eFolderID
```

**I wanted to add a WHERE so it only displays if i.ClosedDate is 30 minutes (or less) more than e.eCreationTime**

Comment: You really haven't provided enough context to answer this question. Are you having problems with your query? Do you want a filter applied to the Dataset or somewhere else in the report? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried and what database server are you using? Can you post your current code?

Comment: **Sorry, I was struggling to explain.**

`select e.eMapName
, e.eFolderName
, i.Status
, i.AssignedTo
, i.ClosedDate
, e.eCreationTime

From ework.eFolder e inner join ework.Incident_Management i
on e.eFolderID = i.eFolderID`

**I wanted to add a WHERE so it only displays if i.ClosedDate is 30 minutes (or less) more than e.eCreationTime**

Comment: I tried the filter option but couldn't get it quite right with the expression

Comment: @Billo I have updated my answer so it can help you with the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139927.aspx) to put something like the following into an expression for the visibility of whatever report element you're trying to hide or display:

```
=DATEDIFF("Minute", e.eCreationTime, i.ClosedDate) <= 30
```

Or a little more explicitly:

```
=IIF(DATEDIFF("Minute", e.eCreationTime, i.ClosedDate) <= 30, True, False)
```

UPDATED:

I see now you're looking for a WHERE clause in T/SQL.  Well, it luckily happens there is also a [DATEDIFF function in T/SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) (separate from the one in the SSIS Expression Editor):

```
select e.eMapName,
e.eFolderName,
i.Status,
i.AssignedTo,
i.ClosedDate,
e.eCreationTime
from ework.eFolder e 
inner join ework.Incident_Management i
on e.eFolderID = i.eFolderID
where datediff(minute, e.eCreationTime, i.ClosedDate) <= 30
```

Does this help?